# How to automate Oracle Smartview data refreshes?

Tags: python, excel, windows, oracle, add-in

We are using Smartview to view the data from our cloud EPBCS,  But it needs to be manually updated everyday. How can we automate this? can we schedule Smartview refreshes using python preferably?
how can we best automate this?
I can't find a library that can refresh SmartView automatically on python and win32com does not work.
Thanks in advance

I tried win32com and it was not available. what are some alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you found the solution for this?
to note that the servername, connectionname when using a oracle smart view connection could be different from a normal ox_Oracle connection.
I have tried with:
`connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connection_name)` 
`smart_view = excel.COMAddIns("Oracle Smart View for Office").Object`
 `and smartview_addin_name = "Oracle Smart View for Office`

I have also found a solution online using pyessbase but this doesn't not exist anynmore
but unfortunatly i was not able to find a solution

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35189633)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to approach this. You need to use the VBA functions from Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E72988_01/DGSMV/ch03s26.html

You can save this to the Excel file or pass it through Python using PyWin32 or XLWings API. Then use either of those to open the file, connect, refresh, save.